# Is the numerator of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2k+1}}$ always a power of $2$ in lowest terms?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Is the numerator of
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2k+1}}
$$
always a power of $2$ in lowest terms, and if so, why? Is there a combinatorial or probabilistic proof of this?

Comment: How much numerical evidence for this do you have?

Comment: This is equal to the product of all even numbers up to $2n$ divided by the product of all odd numbers up to $2n+1$. So the question is why is there enough downstairs to cancel all the odds from upstairs.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Through about $n=50$. Put $\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}\right)$ into Mathematica (or Wolfram Alpha) and check its Taylor series for yourself.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Ah, so $2^n n!\frac{2^n n!}{(2n+1)!}=\frac{2^{2n}}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}$. Yeah, that explains it.

Comment: I edited my answer to add a combinatorial proof of the crucial identity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Proved in edit at the end:* this sum is equal to the fraction 
$${\prod_{i=1}^n 2i\over\prod_{i=1}^{n} 2i+1}$$

Now: $\prod_{i=1}^n 2i=2^n n!$

and $\prod_{i=1}^{n} {2i+1}={(2n+1)!\over \prod_{i=1}^n 2i}={(2n+1)!\over 2^n n!}$

Therefore your sum is equal to $${(2^n n!)^2\over (2n+1)!}={2^{2n}\over(2n+1){2n \choose n}}$$

Where the result is now clear.

---

**Edit: combinatorial proof of the identity ${\prod_{i=1}^n 2i\over\prod_{i=1}^{n} 2i+1}$.**

Define the sum $$S_{n,m}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2k+m}}$$
**Claim:** for any $n,m$, one has $$S_{n,m}={\prod_{i=1}^{n}2i\over \prod_{i=0}^{n}2i+m }$$

The claim implies the desired identity when $m=1$.

**Proof of the claim:**

The identity ${n+1\choose k}={n\choose k}+{n\choose k-1} \ $ implies immediately that $$S_{n+1,m}=S_{n,m}-S_{n,m+2}$$

Moreover, the claim holds when $n=0$, where $S_{0,m}=\frac1m$

The result follows now from an immediate induction on $n$.

Comment: This is nice, but I think I had something more bijective in mind. Like an application of the sieve method. Say, we consider the set $\{0,\pm1, \pm2,\dots,\pm n\}$ and the properties $P_i=$ something happens at $\pm i$, $i=1,\dots,n$. Then see where we have exactly $0$ properties, i.e. something happens only at $0$.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein Interesting. I'll try to think in this direction too.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the function
$$
F(q)=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} q^{2k}=(1-q^2)^n
$$
If we denote the sum you want to calculate by $\phi=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k}\frac{1}{2k+1}$, then
$$
\phi = \int_0^1 F(q)dq = \int_0^1 (1-q^2)^n dq=\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}
$$
where $k!!=k(k-2)(k-4)\cdots$. This simplifies to
$$
\phi=\frac{2^{2n} (n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}
$$
Now note that
$$
{2n \choose n}=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\in \mathbb{Z}
$$
so $(n!)^2$ divides $(2n)!$ which in turn means it divides $(2n+1)!$. So the numerator of $\phi$ is necessarily a power of $2$ in lowest terms.

Comment: Thanks! That explains it. But what would be a combinatorial/probabilistic proof of this identity? Kind of curious about that still. Although, that’s probably deducible from the answer somehow.

Comment: If you insist on the combinatorial/probabilistic proof, let me think about it a bit. I'm sure there is one.

Comment: @Hamed (+1) I got one, if you are interested :)

Comment: It's too bad I can't accept both answers, this one is very good, too.