# I want to compute this thing $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2k+1}}$ without a dropped induction.

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

I want to compute this expression without using a ' known induction to apply':

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2k+1}}$$

I saw this one :[Is the numerator of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2k+1}}$ always a power of $2$ in lowest terms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2731637/561798)

First proof is by induction, the second one uses hypergeometric function which is a bit to non-elementary.

Thanks.

(I tried Pascal, then some identity on binomial coeff , the sum I want to calculate is from the associated integral from zero to one)

Comment: Seeing your user name, may I bet that you are French ? Just out of curiosity : where are you located ? I am in Pau.

Comment: Consider $(x^2+1)^n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}x^{2k}$, then $\int{}(x^2+1)^ndx$ is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}$. Can you progress somehow from here?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I started from the integral to go to the sum, but you can see it just as $ \int_0^1 (x^2+1)^n dx $ . I tought about kind of Cesaro summation (because the present sum is in fact an average , weighted by binomial coefficient of whom the sum gives $2^n$ .

Comment: Coming from Rhônes-Alpes .

Comment: Coming from Rhônes-Alpes .Does Pau has a well preserved old-city ?